# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable не могу найти в чем ошибка

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

Есть такой код. Идея в том, чтобы ускорить обработку большого датафрейма мультипроцессингом.

```
class Get_data(object):

def __init__(self):

    self.data_path = '/../'
    self.t = "preAVL"
    self.num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    self.num_partitions = 20


def getDF(self):
    df_preAVL = pd.DataFrame()
    search_string = self.data_path + "/*" + self.t + "*"
    for filename in glob.glob(search_string):
        try:
            df_preAVL = df_preAVL.append(pd.read_excel(filename))
        except:
            print "Problem file: {}".format(filename)
            raise
            df_preAVL = df_preAVL.reset_index(drop=True)
    del df_preAVL['trainUpTime']
    return df_preAVL

def setLossCarByIMEI(self, row):
    if not pd.isnull(row['car']):
        return row['car']
    if pd.isnull(row['dev_imei']):
        return np.NAN

    try:
        return map_imei2car_id[row['dev_imei']]
    except:
        pass

    return np.NAN

def parallelize_dataframe(self,df, func):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, self.num_partitions)
    pool = Pool(self.num_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.imap(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df

def pre_AVL(self,df):
    df['car'] = df.apply(s.setLossCarByIMEI, axis=1)
    return df
```

Вызываю таким образом

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
s = Get_data()
df_preAVL=s.getDF()
#df_preAVL = s.pre_avl(df_preAVL)

df_preAVL = s.parallelize_dataframe(df_preAVL, s.pre_AVL(df_preAVL))



print df_preAVL
```

Полный текст ошибки такой :

`TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable`

Начинает ругаться на :

`df = pd.concat(pool.imap(func, df_split))`

Где у меня ошибка? Импорт необходимых модулей сделан-pandas,multiprocessing и тд

Comment: Что выводит код: `print(type(s.pre_AVL(df_preAVL)), dir(s.pre_AVL(df_preAVL)))`?

Comment: ```/Users/PycharmProjects/SLA_quality/venv/bin/python "/Users/PycharmProjects/SLA_quality/venv/main.py"
(<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, [u'AVLpct', 'T', '_AXIS_ALIASES', '_AXIS_IALIASES', '_AXIS_LEN', '_AXIS_NAMES', '_AXIS_NUMBERS', '_AXIS_ORDERS', '_AXIS_REVERSED', '_AXIS_SLICEMAP', '__abs__', 
.........

```

Comment: все киньте. Но с того что я вижу вы используете `s.pre_AVL(df_preAVL)` как функцию, хотя это не функция.

Comment: все не влезает .скину конец  ```' ...., 'pct_change', 'pipe', 'pivot', 'pivot_table',  'transform', 'transpose', 'truediv', 'truncate', 'tshift', 'tz_convert', 'tz_localize', 'unstack', 'update', 'values', 'var', 'where', 'xs'])```

Comment: отдельно если вызывать ```df_preAVL=s.pre_AVL(df_preAVL)```он выдает датафрейм,который нужен.Просто задача в том, чтобы ускорить процесс обработки датафрейма

Comment: Короче киньте сюда синхронный код,и я вам в ответ кину его паралельный вариант. То как оно сейчас есть, оно работать не может.

Comment: все скинуто как есть в вопросе.В каком смысле синхронный код?

Comment: ну без вызова `pool.imap`

Comment: ок.Тогда вопрос в следующем.Как запустить мультипроцессинг без функции ```def parallelize_dataframe``` ?

Comment: Ок. вы не неверно поняли суть мультипроцессинга. Запустив функцию в отдельном потоке не будет прироста скорости. Конкретно в вашем варианте запуск `df.apply(s.setLossCarByIMEI, axis=1)` в отдельном потоке не даст прироста. Вам нужно что бы сама `df.apply` стала паралельной(что кстати не всегда возможно).   И такая паралельная `apply` уже есть: 
 http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html?highlight=apply#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.apply

Comment: То есть вам нужно викинуть свой `Pool` и `parallelize_dataframe`, а вызов `df.apply` заменить на  http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html?highlight=apply#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.apply

Comment: ok, можно полную Вашу версию=)

Comment: Вы можете выложить небольшой пример вашего DF (например зыпостить результат: `print(df.sample(10).head(10))`) и того что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: `map_imei2car_id` - это `dict` или `Pandas.Series`?

Comment: это dict.Дело в том.что в юпитере все работает без проблем .То есть все функции верные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. мультипроцессинг скорее всего уже используется Pandas и Numpy, чтобы проверить `np.__config__.show()`
2. если попытаться распараллелить самому, то с очень высокой вероятностью получится еще медленнее
3. `getDF` можно немного оптимизировать:

---

```
def getDF(self):
    dfs = []
    search_string = self.data_path + "/*" + self.t + "*"
    for filename in glob.glob(search_string):
        try:
            dfs.append(pd.read_excel(filename).drop('trainUpTime', axis=1))
        except:
            print "Problem file: {}".format(filename)
            raise
            df_preAVL = df_preAVL.reset_index(drop=True) # почему в секции except ???
    return pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

---

4. **самое важное:** `df.apply(s.setLossCarByIMEI, axis=1)` можно и нужно векторизировать (это даст самый большой прирост производительности).
   Если `map_imei2car_id` - словарь вида `{'IMEI':'car_id'}`, то

---

```
df['car'] = df.apply(s.setLossCarByIMEI, axis=1)
```

можно заменить на:

```
mask = df['car'].isnull() & df['dev_imei'].notnull()
df.loc[mask, 'car'] = df.loc[mask, 'dev_imei'].map(map_imei2car_id)
```

---

**Пример:**

имеем следующий DF:

```
In [190]: df
Out[190]:
    car dev_imei
0   NaN    IMEI1
1  car2    IMEI2
2   NaN    IMEI3
3  car4    IMEI4
4   NaN      NaN
5   NaN    IMEIx
```

и словарь:

```
In [191]: map_imei2car_id
Out[191]: {'IMEI1': 'car1', 'IMEI2': 'car2', 'IMEI3': 'car3', 'IMEIx': 'carX'}
```

Замена:

```
In [192]: mask = df['car'].isnull() & df['dev_imei'].notnull()

In [193]: df.loc[mask, 'car'] = df.loc[mask, 'dev_imei'].map(map_imei2car_id)
```

Результат:

```
In [194]: df
Out[194]:
    car dev_imei
0  car1    IMEI1
1  car2    IMEI2
2  car3    IMEI3
3  car4    IMEI4
4   NaN      NaN
5  carX    IMEIx
```

Comment: вопрос тогда такой.А почему в обычном юпитер ноутбуке отлично работает это : ```def parallelize_dataframe(df, func):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
    pool = Pool(num_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.imap(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df

def pre_AVL(df):
    df['car'] = df.apply(setLossCarByIMEI, axis=1)
    return df
df_preAVL = parallelize_dataframe(df_preAVL,pre_AVL)```

Comment: @AndrewKonstantinov, что значит отлично? Вы делали замеры по скорости и сравнивали ваше решение и мое?

Comment: Ваше решение быстрее.Я соглашусь.Но почему мое решение не работает в pycharm?а работает в ноутбуке?Про векторизацию это да, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @AndrewKonstantinov, я не работал с PyCharm... [Посмотрите здесь ...](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000384464-Problem-using-multiprocess-with-IPython)

Comment: в принципе у Вас хорошее решение и более простое .Спасибо

Comment: @AndrewKonstantinov, просто я уже видел подобные вопросы (multiprocessing) по Pandas/Numpy/SciPy на английской версии SO и практически всегда находилось векторизированное решение, которое оказывалось значительно быстрее попыток распараллелить невекторизированную функцию ;)

Comment: @AndrewKonstantinov, в pycharm у вас, возможно, не установлены необходимые библиотеки, потому и не работает